# Building 32bit version of libtorrent on osx using boost with python bindings

Tags: c++, python, boost, libtorrent

I'm running the following build command from the /bindings/python directory of libtorrent

```
./bjam boost=system link=static address-model=32 toolset=darwin architecture=x86 release
```

But I'm getting the following errors

```
/opt/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:75:24: error: patchlevel.h: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:78:2: error: #error Python 2.2 or higher is required for this version of Boost.Python.
/opt/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:142:21: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Finally resulting in

```
...failed darwin.compile.c++ bin/darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-32/architecture-x86/link-static/src/module.o..
```

Can anyone point to where I'm getting messed up?

Comment: Those errors indicate that bjam cannot locate the python header files.  Verify that the python header files are installed (usually distributed in a python-devel package).

Answer (score 1):

The stupid question: Do you have python intalled? And if you do have it installed, but not in a standard place, you must tell bjam where to find it.

Oh, and was boost built with python support?

Comment: Hey, your thoughts pointed me in the direction of this, all building now :) http://www.geero.net/2011/03/install_pythonmagick_mac_os_x/

Comment: Now getting these errors

darwin.link.dll ../../bin/darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-32/architecture-x86/boost-link-shared/threading-multi/libtorrent.dylib.0.16.11
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/sw/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/g++/lib'
ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Any ideas?